# Discord.py | Узнать ID сообщения от бота

Tags: discord, discord.py

Допустим, есть бот.

```
(avatar) Bot
```

Он отправил сообщение.

```
(avatar) Bot: lol
```

Т.е. в нем написано:

```
await ctx.send("lol")
```

И под ним есть реакция, где можно выбрать любую

```
(avatar) Bot: lol
reaction | 1, reaction | 1
```

Нужно узнать ID сообщения, чтобы отреагировать на нажатие какой либо реакции. Но как? Или есть другие способы отреагировать на нажатие любой реакции?

Answer (score 1):

При отправке сообщения, сохраните его объект в переменную. Далее из этого объекта можете получить все, что хотите. Список атрибутов и методов сообщений и других объектов есть в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)

ID можно получить вот так:

```
msg = await bot.send('lol')
id = msg.id
```